# Do I need --skip-lock-tables with --single-transaction?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqldump

I am performing regular backups using mysqldump on a schema consisting entirely of InnoDB tables.  The [mysqldump documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) has this to say about `--single-transaction`:

> The --single-transaction option and the --lock-tables option are mutually exclusive because LOCK TABLES causes any pending transactions to be committed implicitly.

Yet approx 1 bazillion blog posts and answers here (and elsewhere on the stack exchange network) recommend:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables my_database > my_database.sql
```

If the two options are mutually exclusive, I would think that specifying `--single-transaction` should be enough.  However the [docs also state](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt) this about `--opt`:

> This option, enabled by default, is shorthand for the combination of --add-drop-table --add-locks --create-options --disable-keys --extended-insert --lock-tables --quick --set-charset.

Which leads me to believe that `--lock-tables` is on by default.

**Do I need to specify `--skip-lock-tables` along with `--single-transaction` or is merely setting the latter enough to ensure tables are not locked during a dump?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the `--single-transaction` option, it turns off `--lock-tables`. That's what the documentation means when it says they are mutually exclusive.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/client/mysqldump.cc#L1076

```
  if (opt_single_transaction || opt_lock_all_tables) lock_tables = false;
```

Comment: source code for the win.  thank you!

Comment: it's amazing how hundreds of people writing about this are adding both options and this isn't documented anywhere that I could find. if you add up all of the wasted keystrokes i'm pretty sure it amounts to at least an afternoon at the park with your family :-)

Comment: How would your family feel about having to spend 10 seconds in the park with each of hundreds of strangers? (j/k)